# How to quickly re-load the new code for a ClojureScript library I'm developing?

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

I have a project using Figwheel with ClojureScript and I'm developing a ClojureScript library. My cycle involves modifying the library, installing with `lein install` and then using it from the app.

The last part is the one I'm not sure about. Nothing short of `lein clean` in the app seems to get rid of the previous copy of the library. Having to do a `lein clean` and recompile every time I modify the library is very cumbersome.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could probably add your lib source path to your cljsbuild source path in project.clj

```
:cljsbuild {:builds [{:id "dev"
                      :source-paths ["src" "/my/awesome/lib/src"]}
                      ...}]}
```

so you can simply refer needed namespaces, and figwheel will recompile all the changes both in a lib and in your app. I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0):

the other thing you can do is use the figwheel (reset-autobuild) command. This can be useful as it will do an implicit lein clean before re-building your cljs files.